# I dual-booted Ubuntu and Windows, and now I want to switch to another distro

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, reset, reinstall

Alright, so the other day I installed Ubuntu GNOME alongside Windows 8. Now I've decided that the latest version is just too buggy, and I want to switch to stock Ubuntu.

Instead of just installing the Unity environment, I want to erase Ubuntu GNOME and restart fresh. I've messed a lot of stuff up with my graphics settings, installed LXDE to try to fix problems I was having, etc. It's just a mess and I want to restart.

How do I do this without messing up my system? Both Ubuntu and Windows are installed in UEFI mode.

Thanks!

Comment: Depending on version DO NOT use an auto install option. Only Something Else. Older versions including 14.04 have a bug on reinstall where they may say they are overwriting Ubuntu but erase entire drive. So good backups & Something Else. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1265192 Be sure to boot live installer in UEFI mode: http://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installation

Answer (score 0):

Just install the new distro on top of the old Linux install.  You just need to know how large the partition is, so that you can see which it is during install.  Just make sure to format that partition and that partition ONLY during install.